# Modify a CSS with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i’m having trouble changing the class of a CSS with javascript, whenever I call the element and try to change the style it returns null, almost like the element doesn’t have the class associated my code looks like this

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box1');

box.style.backgroundColor = red;
```

```css
.box {
      background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id=“box1“ class="box">
```

Somehow when you log in the console the style of box (of the js) the background color is empty

Comment: The variable `red` is not defined in your code, so this should be a syntax error.

Comment: put red inside quotes => "red"

Comment: Also don't know if this is just a copy-paste error but the quotes around your id attribute look off `<div id=“box1” class="box">`, this should be `<div id="box1" class="box">` So you should at least get 2 errors in your console if you run the code.

Comment: Als, since your box has no size, you wouldn't even see the result. Also also, you should include the `console.log` statement that does not output what you expect it to, as we don't know if you made a mistake in there.

Answer (score 1):

Use correct quotations around your ID attribute. Also use "red" instead of just red.

```js
  var box = document.getElementById('box1');
  box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```css
 .box {
  background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box">
CSS
</div>
```

Comment: you have not closed "div" tag

Comment: thanks, you are right. that's because I just copy-pasted it from OP. Added it now.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
  var box = document.getElementById('box1');
  box.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //you were just typing red earlier
  box.style.width="100px";
  box.style.height="100px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".box").css("background-color", "red");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=“box1” class="box">Box 1</div>
```

Comment: what's the need for setTimeout() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change CSS using .css() of jquery.

**Try:**

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#box1').css("background-color", "red")
 })
```

```css
 .box {
  background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" class="box">
CSS
</div>
```